# Robolectric: How to specify the locale to en-US or fr to test string formatting?

Tags: android, robolectric

In a test, we want to test string formatting in English and French. How to specify the locale in robolectric?

The method in this post doesn't work:
[Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what did when unit tests involve locale:

1. Get the context from Robolectric
2. Use the context to getString (singular/plural forms) to construct expected strings directly.
3. Check it against the output from the methods that return strings.

Answer (score 4):

Robolectric now includes an `@Config` annotation that you can put on your unit tests to specify things like this. See [here](http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2013/05/configuring-robolectric-20.html) for more info.